# Не могу закрыть модалку bootstrap чистым javascript

Tags: javascript, bootstrap

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/ - хотел использовать модальное окна bootstrap, возникла проблема закрытия модально окна уже голову сломал и не знаю как скрыть модалку, у меня в модальном окне есть кнопка сохранить когда пользователь нажимает видпраляеться запрос на backend после того когда запрос пришел мне нужно закрыть модалку, закрытие модалкы нужно сделать на числом javascript

Answer (score 0):

Вот так можно, но нужна кнопка отмена или крестик, у которого будет стоять `data-dismiss="modal"` ну и если окно такое не одно, то кнопку нужно искать внимательнее

```js
function xhrSimulate(){
  setTimeout(() => $("#modalExample [data-dismiss=modal]").trigger({ type: "click" }), 1000)
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" 
        data-target=".bs-example-modal-lg">open modal
</button>
<div id="modalExample" class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" 
      aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-body"><p class="body-message centered">modal content</p></div>
      <div class="modal-footer no-borders">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="xhrSimulate()">xhr simulate</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">cancel</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Это не чистый JS, а с использованием библиотеки JQuery
Правильный вариант, получить элемент, потом экземпляр модального окна по элементу:

```
var modal = document.getElementById('modal');
var modalInstance = bootstrap.Modal.getInstance(modal);
modalInstance.hide();
```

А лучше изначально создавать модальное окно в JS, тогда можно так:

```
var myModal = new bootstrap.Modal(document.getElementById('myModal'), options);
// тут код который открывает окно, а потом можно добавить событие в котором уже будете закрывать его.
MyModal.hide();
```

Comment: Хотел это комментарием написать к ответу "Stranger in the Q"

Comment: Почему вы думаете, что это комментарий, а не полноценный ответ?